# chenge value from string to number in fast report

Tags: format, crosstab, fastreport

I Have a script in db cross tab in fast report and I whant display value format from string to number(%2.0n) and separator ,

```
procedure DBCross1OnPrintCell(Memo: TfrxMemoView; RowIndex, ColumnIndex, CellIndex: Integer; RowValues, ColumnValues, Value: Variant);
begin
if ColumnIndex = 0 then
if Value <> null then 
  Set('Var0', Value)
else
  Set('Var0', 0);
  if DBCross1.IsGrandTotalColumn(ColumnIndex) then 
Memo.Text :=VarToStr(value- Get('Var0'));
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
procedure DBCross1OnPrintCell(Memo: TfrxMemoView; RowIndex, ColumnIndex, CellIndex: Integer; RowValues, ColumnValues, Value: Variant);
begin
  if ColumnIndex = 0 then
    if Value <> null then 
      Set('Var0', Value)
    else
      Set('Var0', 0);
    if DBCross1.IsGrandTotalColumn(ColumnIndex) then 
       Memo.Text := Format('%2.0n', [StrToFloat(VarToStr(value- Get('Var0')))]);
```

end;

Comment: Dear gpi
Hi and very very tnx For asked to my questions